# change url servername and domain on internal sites hosted in IIS

Tags: iis, dns

scenario:

server name: `server`

domain: `abc.de.ca`

I have multiple internal websites hosted in IIS such as

`server.abc.de.ca/test1`

`server.abc.de.ca/test2`

`server.abc.de.ca/test3`

These sites are available on the internal network

Now I want to hide the `server.abc.de.ca` part of the URL such as custom name such as `custom/test1`, `custom/test2`, `custom/test3`

How can this be done?
This is for `window server 2022`

Comment: Like you tagged, this question is DNS related and should be redirected to your network administrators or a site like ServerFault. Off topic here as not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change the domain name, you can try using url rewrite

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^server.abc.de.ca$" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://custom/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```